# fileproviderd is using up 300% system resources on 10.15 beta

Tags: macos

I see fileproviderd is using up 300% system resources on 10.15 beta and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.  Fan is wining away on my MacBook pro and the battery drains in a few hours.

Comment: You can't use Stack Exchange to troubleshoot, as the beta is under NDA. You'll have to report it to Apple.

Comment: File a Radar. That's why you're running the beta.

Comment: 25-Aug-2019, first install of beta on my Mac with 10.15 Beta (19A536g), same issue. Does not look like Apple is going to fix this. Just checked, no curtesy post on OpenRadar for any radar filed either... http://openradar.appspot.com/page/1

Answer (score 9):

I'm on macOS catalina beta *(build number 19A512f)*, here's a shotgun approach to fixing this problem, at least temporarily.

1. In **Activity Monitor.app**, sort processes by CPU usage, choose **fileproviderd**, **iCloudDrive**, and **cloudd** and force quit them.
2. Go to `System Preferences > Apple id > iCloud` and uncheck `Optimize Mac Storage`.
3. Still in `System Preferences > Apple id > iCloud` and uncheck `iCloud Drive`, keep a local copy or not (I chose not), normally it was already synced before then there is a copy of your data in the cloud so no worries.
4. Now when you no longer have `iCloud Drive` active, we are going to clear some caches, but before everything again in **Activity Monitor.app** force quit **fileproviderd**, **iCloudDrive**, and **cloudd**.

   Go to `/Users/<your-username>/Library/Application Support` (this directory is hidden, but you can access it with `Finder > Go > Go to folder`, after typing the start of each path you can type tab to autocomplete) in it you delete `FileProvider` folder.

   Then, go to `/Users/<your-username>/Library/Caches` and `/Library/Caches` and `/System/Library/Caches` and delete everything in them (don't worry it's just system and application caches).
5. Reboot
6. (optional) With the command line, remove the `iCloud Drive (archive)` folder in your home `/Users/<your-username>` with the command: `sudo rm -rf /Users/<your-username>/iCloud\ Drive\ \(archive\)`, you can also move it someplace else to safe keep it with the mv command.
7. Verify that everything is working smooth and no process is out of control in **Activity Monitor.app** and go to `System Preferences > Apple id > iCloud` and re-check `iCloud Drive`, wait for it to enable itself properly.
8. Make sure `System Preferences > Apple id > iCloud > Optimize Mac Storage` remains unchecked.
9. That's it, your system should now be working smoothly without **fileprovider** canibalizing the CPU. I suggest *you never, ever try to force download a folder*, whenever you need a file it will automatically download it for you, but force downloading it may screw things up again, I advise for the moment to leave as is.

Make sure everything is ok in **Activity Monitor.app** and in `Console.app > errors and warnings`. Check that fileproviderd is no longer throwing up tons of errors per seconds.

Only thing that can still make **fileproviderd** eat up some CPU along with it is **photoanalysisd** which does facial recognition on all your photos, you can check up the advancement of this task in `Photos.app > People`.

Comment: I was having an issue with OneDrive on Monterey causing `fileproviderd` to cannibalize a whole core non-stop after an update to 12.3. Clearing out my user cache, the `FileProvider` folder, and then killing the runaway process stopped the whole mess. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

This bug is caused by iCloud-Drive. If you go to settings and disable iCloud-Drive, fileproviderd should stop using up the system resources. Hopefully iCloud-Drive will work as expected in the next beta.

Answer (score 2):

As a very temporary fix you can kill the fileproviderd process. If you don't know how to do that you *really* shouldn't be running a developer preview release.

`ps -ax | grep fileproviderd`

then kill -9 the process id.

Comment: Easier to `pkill fileproviderd`   but regardless, just bounces back into over 100% processor load.

Answer (score 1):

Just putting in that I'm still seeing this issue on public beta 19A501i.
Have tried to disable the optimise storage but that didnt fix it so my next move will be to turn off icloud full-stop.
I have been putting this off though hoping that an updated beta might fix the issue firstly.

Comment: I think you should add more illustrations to support the Post!!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on beta 1 and what helped me solved the problem besides turning off icloud drive was to uncheck "optimize mac storage".

Answer (score 0):

This problem is resolved with the Catalina Update from July 3rd on my MacMini

Answer (score 0):

When I was looking for a solution to my fileproviderd woes on Monterey 12.6.7, I ran across this answer several times. In case anyone else with these issues ends up here, I'll share my solution.

Tresorit can spike fileproviderd. Took a lot of trial and error to figure this out, as Tresorit runs a hidden daemon which doesn't show up in LaunchControl.

[image: Tresorit record in Console]

For those who don't know Tresorit, it's a file sync service like Dropbox but more secure. It's supposed to be E2E zeroknowledge sync.

What is was not – an issue with iCloud. Signing in and out of iCloud and restarting my computer was just a futile waste of time.

Turning off Finder integrations of various kinds in Tresorit preferences helped. I have not yet removed Tresorit from my machine (I will; chose NextCloud instead).

NextCloud, MegaSync did not spike fileproviderd (probably don't use it).

Apparently Dropbox and OneDrive also use Apple's fileproviderd agent. Check them carefully if you use them and face extended fileproviderd spikes.